# Limit number of a user for ssh tunneling

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, tunnel

i want to limit the ssh tunneling per user
I did create a user with only ssh tunneling permission ( no shell, no directory ) now I want to limit this user not be able to connect multi devices simultaneously to this tunnel ( I don't want to bind device's mac address to the user since they might change their device or firewall things ).
does changing the user maxlogin on /etc/security/limits affect ssh tunneling limits?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does, example below.

The post
[How can I disconnect ssh users, or limit the number of ssh logins?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227316/how-can-i-disconnect-ssh-users-or-limit-the-number-of-ssh-logins)
has this in an
[answer by Dmitry Alexeyev](https://serverfault.com/questions/227316/how-can-i-disconnect-ssh-users-or-limit-the-number-of-ssh-logins/245348#245348):

> Setting up maxlogins limit actually works here. Just make sure you use
> '-' limit type, not 'hard'.
>
> ```
> user1          -       maxlogins       1
> ```

Note that the post demanded a method for preventing more than one user
to connect to the tunnel at a time, and the answer was
by setting `maxlogins` to `1` for both users.

Comment: so this is wrong?
user1   hard  maxlogins 1

Comment: Wrong ? It's supposed to work as you want. The user can only connect once.

Comment: check this please
https://pastebin.com/YfRb37Cb

Comment: The line you added is not exactly as in my answer.

Comment: i still can connect with 3  I did add this : user1 - maxlogins 1 and restart the ssh&reboot. are you sure this work for tunneling?

Comment: I don't have the environment for testing. Yours might be different than in the post I quoted.